# Multilingual website with a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a multilingual site in MVC and I reached the current results, but I'm not sure it's the right way.

I have created a class named `changeLanguage` to change the language:

```
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(String LanguageAbbrevation)
        {
            if (LanguageAbbrevation != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);

            }
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
            cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");

        }
```

Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LanguageTB context = new LanguageTB();
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
            if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);

            }

            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");

            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AboutUs()
 {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Language"];
        var categoryList = context.SiteContents.Where(x => x.LanguageTB.CultureCode==cookie.Value)).ToList();
        return View(categoryList);
    }
```

I'm doing this again and again for every view:

```
 public ActionResult AllAttorney()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Language"];
    var employeelist = context.Employees.Where(x => x.LanguageTB.CultureCode== mainLanguage.lb).ToList();
    return View(employeelist);
}
```

View:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
   <li> <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage","Language",new { LanguageAbbrevation = "en" })">en</a></li>
   <li> <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage","Language",new { LanguageAbbrevation = "az" })">az</a></li>
   <li> <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeLanguage","Language",new { LanguageAbbrevation = "ru" })">ru</a></li>                                 
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="@Url.Action("AllAttorney", "Home")">@RHome.MAttorney</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home")">@RHome.MAboutUs</a>                               
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="@Url.Action("caseResult", "Home")">@RHome.MNews</a>                                            
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Language table:

```
  [Table("LanguageTB")]
public partial class LanguageTB
{
    public LanguageTB()
    {
        Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        SiteContents = new HashSet<SiteContent>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CultureName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SiteContent> SiteContents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need to ask you to undo/rollback the edit. It is not allowed now that you have received an answer.... otherwise me or someone else will need to do it :-]

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers): _**Do not change the code in the question after receiving an answer.** Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site._

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know that.I got it back.
.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Too many `Language` Repetitions

You use the `"Language"` key a lot. What if you decide to rename it sometime? You'll need to search everywhere for this string. It'd be better if you encapsulated it or used a constant. I prefer extensions so it might look like this where you try to get the cookie and if it is not null `?` then you get the value.

```
public static class HttpCookieCollectionExtensions
{
    public static string Language(this HttpCookieCollection cookies)
    {
        return cookies["Language"]?.Value
    }
}
```

Later in your application you can reuse it everywhere which would result in a nice short and clear code ba also getting rid of this ugly condition:

> ```
>  if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
> ```

---

#### Bug 1

> ```
> else
> {
>     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
>     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
>
> }
> ```

There is a bug in this `else`. Both lines are the same. Did you copy/paste them?

---

#### Setting culture

Another case for encapsulation are the four lines where you set the culture. Just write a new method and put two of them there:

```
public static void SetCulture(string name)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
}
```

---

#### Default culture

Later you should also add a constant for the default cutlure

```
const string DefaultCulture = "en";
```

#### New event handler

Now put everything together and be happy with this pretty nice two-liner event handler:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var language = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Language() ?? DefaultCulture;
    SetCulture(language);
}
```

---

#### Object initializer

You can also shorten the `ChangeLanguage` method by using an object initializer. This means that you replace this three lines

> ```
> HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
> cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
> Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
> ```

with simply this

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Language")
{
    Value = LanguageAbbrevation
});
```

---

#### Bug 2

There is one more bug in your application. When you check for the `LanguageAbbrevation` here you don't set it to any default value if it's null. Consequently setting the cookie to nothing. Why don't you use `en` here or skip setting the cookie by putting it inside the `if`?

> ```
> public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(String LanguageAbbrevation)
> {
>   if (LanguageAbbrevation != null)
>   {
>       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
>       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
>
>   }
>   Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Language")
>   {
>       Value = LanguageAbbrevation
>   });
>   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
>
> }
> ```